# creating installer for powerpoint addin

Tags: windows, windows-installer, powerpoint, office-addins

I have a powerpoint addin  which I want to deploy using installer.

Main requirement is any normal user (non-admin) should be able to install it.

For that I've created a windows installer that copies necessary files to %appdata% and makes registry changes as required under HKCU.

But the **problem** is non-admin user is prompted for admin password when he tries to install the msi.

I ain't writing anything to HKLM and also copying files to users own directory, still encountering this problem.

What approach should I use in order to make my addin install by non-admin user.

I am using VS 2008 SP1.

Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding an uninstall icon to Control Panel?  IIRC, that requires admin rights.  Also, some programs that generate installers allow you to force admin rights.  Have you made sure that this isn't the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This step solved my problem:

`"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\Bin\\MsiInfo.exe\" $(BuiltOuputPath) -w 10`"

where $(BuiltOuputPath) is path to your .msi file.

**Note:** It flips bit 3 of the word count property in the summary information stream to signal no credential prompt is required.

Answer (score 1):

You should also make sure the install type of the package is set to per-user. I don't know if VS has an option to set this or is controlled automatically. Other tools, like [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/), can easily set this from a combo, in this tool available in Install Parameters page.

You can create your installer with the free edition, just make sure you create a ["Simple" project](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-simple.html), it has all the features you need. Any other project types requires a license.